# how do i capture the javascript event of dragging my finger on my iphone?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile

I have a page full of green div's.

```
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
<div class="square">3</div>
<div class="square">4</div>
```

Styled so they take up the full screen:

```
* {font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
.square { background: green; float: left; height: 50%; width: 50%;}
.touch {background: red;}
```

When you mouseenter each div, a class of "touch" gets added to it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.square').bind('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('touch');
  });
});
```

Viewing the page on my iPhone, if I touch one, it turns red (a class gets added it to it, onmouseenter). However if I drag my finger into another div, it does not not turn red (no mouseenter event triggered). I've tried every event I can find, including mobile event plugins, but I can't figure out how to get this effect. here's a jsfiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdMgS/3/

Load that on your phone, and run it. Touch one quarter and it turns red. Leaving your finger on the screen, try dragging your finger from one quarter to another. Nothing happens. What am I missing? Thanks!

UPDATE: here's a jsfiddle with jgestures.js. Load this on your phone:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdMgS/6/embedded/result/

And drag your finger from one square to another. Why do they not all turn green?

UPDATE: here's a jsfiddle with the capture from the other SO thread recommended:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdMgS/7/

Touching a square turns it red, great. But swiping into another square doesn't trigger the addClass. Am I just missing the right event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events  this has kind of been already covered

Comment: dragging would correspond to the touchmove event

Comment: `dragstart`/`touchstart`

Comment: Also, these: http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries would do a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Touchscreen functionality is a great thing to support, with mobile devices on the rise and whatnot, try one of these great libraries:

http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries

I like jGestures:

```
  http://jgestures.codeplex.com
```

as it is a jQuery plugin, very easy to use, and has LOTS of gestures

```
  jQuery('#swipe').bind('swipeone',eventHandler);
```

Comment: Strange, I tried this exact plugin, and it didn't work. I'll give it another try.

Comment: odd, are you running a native app on the phone, or is it a website? Also, don't limit yourself, try other plugins as well.