# HTML 5 and Java, differences in code on android browsers vs. computer browsers

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, browser, compatibility

I would like kindly ask you, are there any differences between using Java code in internet browser on laptop and browser on android device ? When I use application on laptop, everything is ok, but on tablet application is not working (I can't drag and drop objects). I have tryed online diagram application http://www.diagramo.com/editor/editor.php, but is it not working with tablet browser (Google Chrome, Mozilla). Google Chrome should support HTML 5 and Java is enabled ? I found this application very useful for working on computer and tablet. Please where can be the complication in Java - in browser or in application ?

Comment: What do you mean by `java is enabled`? Keep in mind that android browser does **not** have the java plugin.

Comment: Sorry I mean JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sollution seems to be here: [JavaScript mapping touch events to mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events). It is necessary to work with touchevents and use this part of code to set up mobile touch events. Then it works.