# detect mouse hover on overlapping + transparent images

Tags: jquery, canvas, z-index, alpha, hittest

I'm building a little game where the user has buy items to furnish his house.

- I have a lot of items/images; so I decided to use, for each of them, a "matte" (an image) that would define the hoverable zone, rather than drawing a map area for each image.
  *Example* : here's [the displayed couch](http://cargoculte.be/forem/datas/images/objects/OBJ_0005.png), and [its matte](http://cargoculte.be/forem/datas/images/objects/OBJ_0004.png).
  I "convert" the matte into a canvas element, and will check later if the hovered pixel is transparent to detect if the item is hovered.
- The second thing is that a lot of items are overlapping, so I also need to check which layer is on top.

I have **mousemove** event (jQuery) on the house element; bound with the function **getObjectsUnderMouse()**.

Basically, this is how getObjectsUnderMouse() works :

1. Get the mouse coordinates
2. Get the active (displayed) items in the house
3. Filter those items to keep only the ones **where the mouse hits the canvas boundaries**, knowing the item position and width/height)
4. Filter those items to keep only the ones **where the mouse is NOT on a transparent pixel** (canvas)
5. Filter those items to keep only **the one on the top** (z-index)
6. Give that item a *mouseon* class

I was quite happy with my code, which was quite a challenge but works perfectly on Chrome.

The problem I have is that it is slower elsewhere (not a so big deal), but; above all, seems to crash on ipad; and I need my game to run on ipad... :/

Does anyone knows why or have a better solution for this ?

Here's [a demo of the game](http://cargoculte.be/forem/?debug=1), and here's [the javascript file](http://cargoculte.be/forem/assets/js/calm.js) where you can have a look at getObjectsUnderMouse().

Any advice is welcome !

Comment: Any chance of using cocoon.js/phonegap/cordova to wrap as a native iOS app?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, seems this would be too much work.  I need to find a solution to make it run in a website...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a matte canvas contains the information you need to hit-test, keeping a full sized canvas for each matte is expensive in terms of memory. Keeping a canvas for each matte is likely using more resources than your iPad can handle.

Here's a way to greatly reduce your memory usage:

First, crop any extra transparent space out of each of your objects. For example, your couch is 600x400=240000 pixels, but cropping away the empty space shrinks the image to 612x163=99756 pixels. That's a savings of 58% over the original image size. Less pixels means less memory for a matte.

Instead of keeping a full-sized canvas for each object, instead keep an array for each object which only contains the opacity of each pixel in that image. An array value of 1 indicates that pixel is opaque (and is part of the object). An array value of 0 indicates that pixel is transparent (no part of the object is at this pixel).

Then hit-test against the pixel array instead of hit-testing against a matte canvas.

If you test the arrays in z-index order, you can even tell which object is on top of another object.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

// display which object the mouse is over
var $result=$('#result');

// create an array of target objects
var targets=[];
targets.push({ name:'couch', x:25, y:50, hitArray:[], url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/couch.png' });
targets.push({ name:'lamp', x:50, y:30, hitArray:[], url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/lamp.png' });
var imgCount=targets.length;

// load the image associated with each target object
for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
  var t=targets[i];
  t.image=new Image();
  t.image.crossOrigin='anonymous';
  t.image.index=i;
  t.image.onload=start;
  t.image.src=t.url;   
}

// this is called when each image is fully loaded
function start(){

  // return if all target images are not loaded
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}

  // make hit arrays for all targets
  for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
    var t=targets[i];
    t.hitArray=makeHitArray(t.image);
  }

  // resize the canvas back to its original size
  canvas.width=cw;
  canvas.height=ch;   

  // draw all targets on the canvas
  for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
    var t=targets[i];
    t.width=t.image.width;
    t.height=t.image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(t.image,t.x,t.y);
  }

  // listen for events
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}

// Draw a target image on a canvas
// Get the imageData of that canvas
// Make an array containing the opacity of each pixel on the canvas
// ( 0==pixel is not part of the object, 1==pixel is part of the object)
function makeHitArray(img){
  var a=[];
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
    // if this pixel is mostly opaque push 1 else push 0
    a.push(data[i+3]>250?1:0);
  }
  return(a);
}


function handleMouseMove(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Test the mouse position against each object's pixel array
  // Report hitting the topmost object if 2+ objects overlap
  var hit='Not hovering';
  for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
    var t=targets[i];
    var imgX=mouseX-t.x;
    var imgY=mouseY-t.y;
    if(imgX<=t.width && imgY<=t.height){
      var hitArrayIndex=imgY*t.width+imgX;
      if(hitArrayIndex<t.hitArray.length-1){
        if(t.hitArray[hitArrayIndex]>0){
          hit='Hovering over '+t.name;
        }
      }     
    }
  }

  $result.text(hit);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id='result'>Move mouse over objects.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=250></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome reply, thanks a lot !  It still crashes on iPad, I'm trying to figure out why; but anyway it's quite faster now everywhere.
Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome! By any chance are you using cross-domain images? If yes, then you might be running afoul of CORS security.