# convert touch event to mouse events only works every second time

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, touch-event

I am using the following script, to convert touch events to mouse events. It works pretty fine, however between two touch events (for example with panning through data of a diagram) the second event is not triggered. Then the next event is triggered, the next not and so on.

So this is my function to so found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events)

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type = "mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type = "mouseup";   break;
        default:           return;
    }

    // initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view, clickCount, 
    //                screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, 
    //                altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 
                                  first.screenX, first.screenY, 
                                  first.clientX, first.clientY, false, 
                                  false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function init() 
{
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

Anyone knows why this behaviour is like that?

UPDATE: I found out, that the 'first.target' is first 'div.dragcover' and in the second try it'is 'rect' then again 'div.dragcover' and so on. Anyone knows why this is so?

Comment: You don't seem to be converting the touchcancel event into a mouseevent. Is that intentional?

Comment: I do not really need a touchcancel event & I do not know which mouse event I should bind to it, any ideas?

Comment: initMouseEvent is deprecated: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

better use new MouseEvent(...)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds almost like there is a problem with the markup. The target should always be the element the finger actually touched.

Comment: so why is it the same every first touch, then a different one, then again the same then again the different one?

Comment: Perhaps this might help? 

`document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event