# How to select with touch event (iPad) on xtermjs

Tags: xtermjs

[xtermjs](http://%20https://xtermjs.org/) top page has demo section. I can select with mouse click so that I can copy the selection. However, on iPad, I can't select with touch. Is there any way to select on xtermjs for the touch devices, like iPad?

I added touchstart event and could get pageY but I'm not sure how to convert coordinates to cols and rows.. As long as cols and rows there, I think we can use xterm api to select but I can't find a way..

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){ 
  alert(event.touches[0].pageY)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself.. I mapped touch events to mouse events and works well.

[JavaScript mapping touch events to mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events)