# How to convert touch event to mouse drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, drag, touch-event

On implementing drag-n-drop of an image for touch devices, I have a problem converting touch events to mouse events. Events are not dispatched or don't work as supposed. I used this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1781750/1453413) and learnt other answers.

To minimize the question, I'll narrow to the drag event only, without drop. Hopefully if it's solved, the other part will be solved, too. When I drag the image with mouse, I get the desired behavior - the ghostly image and the changed cursor:

[image]

I need to have the same ghostly image when touch-drag on a device, but no luck:

[image]

In order to achieve the desired behavior, I try to simulate a mouse event when touch event happens.

```
<img id="hammer" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oV2e.png" />

<script>
var hammer = document.getElementById("hammer");

hammer.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
hammer.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);

function touchHandler(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";
    switch(event.type) {
        case "touchstart": type = "dragstart"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type = "drag";      break;        
        default:           return;
    }

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 
                                  first.screenX, first.screenY, 
                                  first.clientX, first.clientY, false, 
                                  false, false, false, 0/*left*/, first.target);
    
    this.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HoRn_/xu0961g7/36/)

It seems that the touch events are not converted to drag events. How can I achieve it? If I add EventListeners to `document` instead of `hammer`, I get an error. If I wrap `hammer` with a container div, and addEventListener to the container, it gives no success, too. If I change `type = "drag"` to `type = "mousemove"`, no difference.